Are 57% of STEM graduates in Arab countries women?
In an interview in Nature, molecular biologist Rana Dajani states:

Although up to 57% of all science, technology, engineering and maths (STEM) graduates in Arab countries are women, women are still under-represented as researchers and professors: in 2018, 41% of researchers in Arab countries were women.

("I’m a Palestinian scientist building a more inclusive future", 1 August 2024)
For instance stemwomen.com claims that only 31% of students in UK are women.

According to recent HESA data, 31% of core STEM students in Higher Education in the UK are women or non-binary.

Are 57% of STEM graduates in Arab countries women?

When citing a journal article, it's important to attribute it to the article's author, not just to the journal. In this case, the article is an interview, and the claim is made by the interviewee.  I edited to clarify.

The quote says "up to".  Does that mean 57% in one Arab country and less in the others?

The quote has probably gone through citogenesis. The following UNESCO report is given as the source for the statistic, but the report doesn't support it.

What is an Arab country? Does Morocco or Egypt count as an Arab country? Are we using Arab as a euphemism for predominately Muslim or are you confining it to people from the place you would call Arabia?

@NeilMeyer arab-countries Yes,yes and no.

They don't have the data for all countries
And the data they do have must average significantly below 57%.
I found the UNESCO data for 2018 (and also years prior), and the only Arab country having over 57% of female graduates in "STEM" was Algeria with 58.2%. If "Arab countries" means "League of Arab States", only 6 of 22 are represented in this data.
On a technicality, if we accept weasel words, it could be considered to be true, possibly:

The quote says "up to". Does that mean 57% in one Arab country and less in the others? —GEdgar

Other sources such as World Economic Forum cite the statistic that "34-57% of STEM grads in Arab countries are women", which is approximately the right range for those 6, with the least being Saudi Arabia with 36.8%. But it's still a horrible, confusing way of reporting the data.
However, "Natural Sciences, Mathematics and Statistics", arguably a subcategory of STEM, does show many Arab countries with incredibly high percentages. The leader (worldwide) is the Arab country of Bahrain with 87.2% of graduates being women.
There's a caveat with graduate data, however. Talking about global statistics, World Education Blog says:

As young women are more likely to graduate from university in the majority of countries, however, the share of females in the total number of STEM graduates is slightly misleading. A closer look at the shares of females and males who are STEM graduates shows that the gender gap in tertiary field choices is starker. Only 15% of young women end up being STEM graduates, compared to 35% of young men. Countries with very large absolute gaps in excess of 30 percentage points include Finland, Germany and Sweden. Countries with very large relative gaps include Belgium, Latvia and Spain. In contrast, Mauritania, Samoa and the United Republic of Tanzania are among the few countries with no gap.

Note also that graduating is only one part of the pipeline—many women in Arab countries and elsewhere don't end up in STEM careers.
